# Using the Cauchy-Hadamard Theorem to find a radius of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

> **Cauchy-Hadamard Theorem**
>
> Consider the formal power series $$f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
> c_{n}(z - a)^{n} $$
>
> for $a, c_{n} \in \mathbb{C}$. Then the radius of convergence of $f$
>   at the point $a$ is given by
>
> $$\frac{1}{R} = \limsup_{n\to\infty} (|c_{n}|^{1/n}).$$

Can I use this Theorem on this series:

$$\sum_{n \text{ even}}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{(n - 1)/2} }{\prod_{i = 1}^{(n - 1)/2} 2i + 1} \cdot x^{n}$$

I tried like this:

$$\frac{1}{R} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{(-1)^{(n - 1)/2}}{\prod_{i = 1}^{(n - 1)/2} 2i + 1} \right|^{1/n}$$

Let the limit equal $L$. Then

$$\text{log}(L) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \log\left(\frac{(-1)^{(n - 1)/2}}{\prod_{i = 1}^{(n - 1)/2} 2i + 1} \right) = 0 $$

So $L = e^{0} = 1$ and $R = 1$. Is this right? I'm pretty sure the right answer is $R = \infty$, though. Does it not work because my sum is only going through even $n$?

Comment: $0^{1/n} = 0$ as well, so you're fine. also, I don't think it's obvious that the limit of $\frac{1}{n}\log(\frac{(-1)^{(n-1)/2}}{\prod 2i+1})$ is $0$

Comment: I think that the limit is true because the product grows without bound. The numerator only has a $1$ term. But, using the ratio test with $\lim_{n\to\infty} |\frac{a_{n + 2}}{a_{n}}|$ gave me limit equals $0$, which means convergent for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}|c_n| &= \begin{cases} \left|\frac{(-1)^{(n - 1)/2}}{\prod_{i = 1}^{(n - 1)/2} 2i + 1} \right|^{1/n} & \text{ if } n \text{ is even} \\0 &  \text{ if } n \text{ is odd}\end{cases} \\
&=\begin{cases} \left|\frac{1}{\prod_{i = 1}^{(n - 1)/2} 2i + 1} \right|^{1/n} & \text{ if } n \text{ is even} \\0 &  \text{ if } n \text{ is odd}\end{cases} \\\end{align}

and hence we have \begin{align}\lim\sup |c_n| &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{1}{\prod_{i = 1}^{(n - 1)/2} (2i + 1)} \right|^{1/n} \\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{n!2^n}{(2n)!} \right|^{1/n} \\
&=2 \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^\frac1{2n}(n/e)}{(2n)^\frac1{2n}(2n/e)^2}\\
&=\frac{e}2 \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n }\\&= 0\end{align}

where I have used Stirling approximation.